# How to add noise like depolarising errors in Qiskit SDK 1.0?

Tags: qiskit, programming, qiskit-runtime

I have a question about how to Add my own Noise like depolarising errors to Quantum gates like $H$ gate, $R_y$ gate and $R_{zz}$ gates in Qiskit SDK 1.0 and count it through `qiskit_ibm_runtime` and `BasicSimulator` in Qiskit SDK 1.0